# What it database atomicity?

Tags: database, transactions

I'm trying to use django's `atomic` database API and I realize that I don't actually know what 'atomic' actually means [in this context].

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/):

*Atomicity is the defining property of database transactions. `atomic` allows us to create a block of code within which the atomicity on the database is guaranteed*

What is database atomicity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [database atomicity consistency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664837/database-atomicity-consistency)

Comment: don't really agree.  there's a difference between:
'what is A?' 
and
'what is the difference between A and B?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atomicity is the concept that, within a transaction, either **all** of the operations succeed or **all** of the operations fail. This will prevent the database from being in a possibly corrupted state of partially applied updates to data.

If you want the long and detailed explanation, you can head over to Wikipedia and read the article:

[Atomicity (database systems) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems))